# Can't Access a global view table with SQL by a selected field code converted from a dropdown selection

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-community-edition

**I am using a SQL notebook in Databricks/Spark community edition**

```
%python
education_DF = sqlContext.sql('select * from global_temp.population_Globaltmp_view where `Education` = "2YD"')
display(education_DF)
```

The above code cell works fine and retrieves the desired rows from the view.
However the following code cell gives an error.

I am supbstituting the hard-coded value "2YD" in the WHERE clause, with a **variable** call **education_choice** that contains the same value.

It seems that I am not using variables correctly in SQL. How would I make this work?

```
%python
education_DF = sqlContext.sql('select * from global_temp.population_Globaltmp_view where `Education` = education_choice')
display(education_DF)
```

(This is the error)

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`education_choice`&#39; given input columns: [global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Salary, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Address, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Race, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.MiddleI, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Education, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.HairColor, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Age, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.FullName, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.City, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.FirstName, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.State, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.LastName, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Height, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Fertility, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Employment, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Zip, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Weight, global_temp.population_globaltmp_view.Gender]; line 1 pos 72;
```

I tried the injection method suggested, but got a slightly different error this time. I included a screen shot of the relevant code cells. It seems that the education_choice "2YD" isn't being recognized as a literal but a field or something like that.

Shouldn't 2YD have quotes around it like "2YD"

If I hard code the WHERE clause like this: WHERE Education = "2YD" the queries works fine.

The image bellow is small but if you right click on it and "open in new tap, it is very readable.

[image]

Comment: Use f-string. The variable cannot be used directly when it is in the string.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT

You use the variable education_choice as a hardcoded string. Instead, you should inject the value of education_choice inside the SQL expression string like that.

*edit - wrap the variable with quoets.

```
%python
education_DF = sqlContext.sql('select * from global_temp.population_Globaltmp_view where `Education` = "{}"'.format(education_choice))
display(education_DF)
```

Comment: It tried the "inject" code you suggested, but got a slightly different error. I updated the above question block with the new error and a screen shot of the code cells and error.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your new issue. let me know.

Comment: Thank you, **it works**. The big picture is: A dropdown widget is used to select the education level (Highschool Diploma, 2 Year Degree, MD, PHD, ...) Then the getArgument("education") choice is used to lookup the code "2YD" in a code file. Then this education code is moved to a variable where it is used in the SQL statement to select all from the population table with that education code.